# IN clause equivalent for array property

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

Actually I have two entities A an B, mapped by a Many-To-Many relationship. 
Doctrine represents this relation with both A.bElements and B.aElements attributes which are accessible with DQL, so I would like to use these attributes in my query, because this query includes other where clauses, and doing all the job in the same query looks fine.

I have a subquery which returns some B elements, and I would like to check if there is at least one of these elements present in A.bElements. The problem is the IN clause works only for one value, not an array.

Here is an example of my query (this is for a search engine) :

```
$qb->select('l')
   ->from('AppBundle:Livre', 'l')
   ->where("l.ISBN LIKE :motcle")
   ->orWhere("l.cote LIKE :motcle")
   ->orWhere($qb->expr()->in('l.dessinateurs',
       $em->createQueryBuilder()
          ->select('d.id')
          ->from('AppBundle:Artiste', 'd')
          ->where('d.dessinateur=1')
          ->andWhere('d.nom LIKE :motcle OR d.prenom LIKE :motcle')
          ->setParameter('motcle', '%'.$motcle.'%')
          ->getDql()
   ))
   ->setParameter('motcle', '%'.$motcle.'%');
```

Here I want all the 'Livre' entities which have at least one of the subquery result in their `l.dessinateurs` property.

I know it's possible to realize this work by retriving all the B and A elements separately, and then use php to check if there are common elements. It's also possible to use the join table, but I guess Doctrine aims to avoid the use of a such table directly.

Maybe someone could help me ? Maybe the problem is not clear enough, I could try to reformulate it if necessary. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

The following query works fine :

```
$qb->select('l')
    ->from('AppBundle:Livre', 'l')
    ->join('l.serie', 's')
    ->join('l.editeur', 'e')
    ->join('l.dessinateurs', 'd', 'WITH', 
        'd.nom LIKE :motcle 
        OR d.prenom LIKE :motcle 
        OR l.ISBN LIKE :motcle 
        OR l.cote LIKE :motcle 
        OR l.etat LIKE :motcle 
        OR l.edition LIKE :motcle
        OR s.libelle LIKE :motcle 
        OR e.nom LIKE :motcle')
    ->join('l.auteurs', 'a', 'WITH', 
        'a.nom LIKE :motcle 
        OR a.prenom LIKE :motcle 
        OR l.ISBN LIKE :motcle 
        OR l.cote LIKE :motcle 
        OR l.etat LIKE :motcle 
        OR l.edition LIKE :motcle
        OR s.libelle LIKE :motcle 
        OR e.nom LIKE :motcle')
    ->setParameter('motcle', '%'.$motcle.'%');
```

Unfortunately I have to repeat the others LIKE clause in both join, but this is another problem. The ccKep's answer below is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give this a shot:

```
$qb->select('l')
   ->from('AppBundle:Livre', 'l')
   ->join('l.dessinateurs', 'd', 'WITH', 'd.dessinateur=1 AND (d.nom LIKE :motcle OR d.prenom LIKE :motcle)')
   ->where("l.ISBN LIKE :motcle")
   ->orWhere("l.cote LIKE :motcle")
   ->setParameter('motcle', '%'.$motcle.'%');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It seems to be the right way, this query gives the correct results when I ask for a dessinateurs. However, the others clauses seems to be ignored (when I use an ISBN in $motcle I don't get any results). I guess it's because the join clause doesn't result in anything, but I want it to be optional : if there is no dessinateurs, but the ISBN (or the cote) matches $motcle the book should be retrived. Should I use another join type ?

Comment: I found a solution, I edit my original question with the working query. Your solution is the accurate answer to my question (about the array property), so this problem is solved. Thanks !